# Geometry - finding the area of the triangle inside a rectangle

Tags: geometry, area

There are two sides of a rectangle with one large and other small. A person walks along the diagonal and saves $1/3$ rd of larger side. Difference between larger and smaller size is $196$. then area of the triangle is ???

**My Try :**

let the larger side is : $l$

then the smaller side is :$l-196$

then,

$l^2 + (l-196)^2 = (l-l/3)^2$

=>......
......
.......

$=>l^2-252l+24696=0$

now i can't solve it

Comment: It may be better to let the smaller side be $x$ and the larger side be $y$.

Comment: please explain...how it will help???and whats wrong in my approach

Comment: Nothing wrong with your approach, though you got the "save one-third" equation wrong. Having two variables sometimes makes calculations easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hypotenuse is not $l-l/3$ but $l+(l-196)-l/3$

Comment: how????its given that

`A person walks along the diagonal and saves 1/3 rd of larger side`

Comment: please explain whats wrong in my approach

Comment: (1) the hypotenuse must be more than the larger side and (2) the saving is comparing walking the hypotenuse against walking both the larger and the smaller side

Comment: ohh... now i understand..so many thanks to both of you